# Run variable length bash script at the top of the hour without cron

Tags: bash, job-scheduling

I have a simple bash script that runs some tasks which can take varying amounts of time to complete (from 15 mins to 5 hours).  The script loops using a for loop, so that I can run it an arbitrary number of times, normally back-to-back.

However, I have been requested to have each iteration of the script start at the top of the hour.  Normally, I would use cron and kick it off that way, every hour, but since the runtime of the script is highly variable, that becomes trickier.

It is not allowable for multiple instances of the script to be running at once.

So, I'd like to include the logic to wait for 'top of the hour' within the script, but I'm not sure of the best way to do that, or if there's some way to (ab)use 'at' or something more elegant like that.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why does the run duration of the script affect whether you use `cron`? If the script takes less than an hour to run in all cases, it should be no issue. If it takes longer, then it's an issue to be addressed whether or not you use `cron`.

Comment: you need to tell us (in your question, not as a comment) if it OK for multiple copies of the script to be running. If you start every hour, while 5 hour versions are running, then you have 2 copies (or more) of your process running. I'm assuming that is NOT what you want, but its not clear from your problem definition.

Comment: `sleep $(( ( 60 - $(date +%M) ) * 60 ))`? That'll get it within 60 seconds. You could get it within a second if you captured both the current minute and second, and changed the formula accordingly, but I don't know if it'd be worth the effort...

Comment: Within 60 seconds is just fine.  Thanks twalberg!  They're trying to line these runs up with hourly Oracle AWRs, so that level of accuracy is great.

Answer (score 2):

You can still use cron. Just make your script use a lock file. With the `flock` utility you can do:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 42> /tmp/myscriptname.lock
flock -n 42 || { echo "Previous instance still running"; exit 1; }

rest of your script here
```

Now, simply schedule your job every hour in cron, and the new instance will simply exit if the old one's still running. There is no need to clean up any lock files.

Comment: Oh, very cool -- I had never heard of flock before.  That's going into the toolbox!  Thank you.